# Pricing for SQL database/ per SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I’m trying to understand if I pay per SQL database or per SQL Server. 
Lets suppose I have:

1 sql server on basic bill plan 5 DTU with:
database1
database2
database3

1 sql server on basic bill plan 10 DTU with:
database1
database2
database3

Let’s suppose they are 24 h per day all the month. So I will pay 3 * 5DTU + 3 * 10DTU or 1 * 5DTU + 1 * 5DTU?

Answer (score 1):

You do not pay per logical servers you pay per databases when talking about  Azure SQL Database based on DTU model. Every 5 DTU database cost $0.0067 per hour, an approximate $4.90/month with automated backups included of 7 days retention period for free. If you want long-term backups, you have to pay extra. The approximate monthly cost I gave you does not include [bandwidth](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/) usage (data going out of Microsoft datacenter). Use [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) pricing calculator for your convenience.

For every 10 DTU database you have to pay an approximate $14.72/month ($0.0202 per hour) per database. That 10 DTU database includes automated backups with 35-days retention period.

There is no licensing cost with the DTU model.

An Azure SQL Database feature that may cost you extra if you enable it is Advanced Threat Detection.

Whenever you scale up a database you pay per every hour you consume of the new tier. If you scale up in the middle of an hour, you pay that hour with the cost of the most expensive tier the database was assigned on that hour.

Answer (score -1):

StackOverflow is probably the wrong forum:  [Serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) is probably a better place to post this question.

Nevertheless, here's what Microsoft has to say on the subject:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers
>
> Azure SQL Database enables you to easily purchase fully managed PaaS
>   database engine that fits your performance and cost needs. Depending
>   on the deployment model of Azure SQL Database, you can select the
>   purchasing model that fits your needs:
>
> [Logical
>   servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-logical-servers)
>   in Azure SQL Database offers two purchasing models for compute,
>   storage, and IO resources: a DTU-based purchasing model and a
>   vCore-based purchasing model. Within this purchasing model, you can
>   choose single databases or elastic pools.
>
> [Managed
>   Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance)
>   in Azure SQL Database only offer the vCore-based purchasing model.
>
> ...
>
> [DTU-based
>   model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers#what-are-database-transaction-units-dtus)
>     This model is based on a bundled measure of compute, storage, and IO
>   resources. Compute sizes are expressed in terms of Database
>   Transaction Units (DTUs) for single databases and elastic Database
>   Transaction Units (eDTUs) for elastic pools.

If this is a "production server", you need to evaluate your expected workload to make an "informed decision".  If you're just looking for a "development environment", your choice is simple: go for "Basic" and "DTU-based Model".  You basically don't pay for whatever you don't use :)

Here's another good Microsoft link to help you better understand your options:

- [Choosing a DTU-based service tier, compute size, and storage resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-dtu)

PS:
I'm unclear from your example if you have two plans, two servers and six different databases (three for each server/each plan).

Comment: Thank you Paul for the detailed information, I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong about Price Tiers and SQL Databases.

Is the price paid per server or per database?

Comment: The DTU model is per-database.  A database resides on a (virtual) server and becomes available when you subscribe to a plan.  Plans are tiered.  Refer to the above links for more information.  Remember, too a) a database typically requires storage, b) DB operations require CPU and bandwidth, c) the database, in turn, is used by application(s), which require their own, additional resources in terms of host, storage, CPU and bandwidth.